# Is it possible to switch between GIT commits?

Tags: git

I am currently trying to learn about git and have committed 2 changes to a project so far:

```
oshiro@debian:/var/www$ git log

commit 4fd249jf039jf49rj905482h794g805h4g53943h
Author: oshiro <oshiro@mail.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 12 15:07:00 2014 +0000

    removed junk from initial version

commit 39fru438439fj3498521490u53945u854u3084ut        
Author: oshiro <oshiro@mail.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 12 14:53:40 2014 +0000

    initial messy project version

oshiro@debian:/var/www$
```

Is it possible for me to switch between the initial messy project version and removed junk from initial version?

Comment: `git checkout 39fru438439fj3498521490u53945u854u3084ut` or any commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a branch without the commit "removed junk from initial version", you can do

```
git checkout 39fru438439fj3498521490u53945u854u3084ut
```

And if you want to create a named branch out of this commit, you can do

```
git checkout -b new_branch 39fru438439fj3498521490u53945u854u3084ut
```

Answer (score 3):

Just checkout whichever commit you want.

```
git checkout 'commit'
```